# How to model the pair of pants (mathematic) with a clean topology?

Tags: modeling

Iam trying to make this model, to no avail.
Any advices, guys?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi :). You've clearly modelled it, so what exactly is the problem? :)

Comment: Iam sorry I forgot to mention, but I downloaded that 3D picture from google. It's topology is very clean, and I want to be able to at least recreate that.

Comment: Hi :). Here's [the article from 2016](https://mathvis.academic.wlu.edu/2016/02/09/constructing-a-pair-of-pants/) about making this exact model. It also includes a [thingiverse download link](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1279118). Someone will surely help if you get stuck anywhere :)

Comment: much obliged it Michal, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more flexible workflow than the one linked by @Jachym, in Blender. Apart from anything else, a Catmull-Clark subdiv. of a square gives a rounded-square, not a good approximation of a circle, so I feel there are a couple of steps left out, there?

[image]

- Create a **2D** Poly-type Curve, with a U resolution of 1.
- Give it a native 'Round' bevel in its 'Data' tab > 'Geometry' Panel with an odd resolution. (5 seems good)
- Assign a *Mirror* modifier, with 'Bisect' in the mirror-axis, and a Subdivision Surface, so you can see what you're doing.

Now you can adjust the curve and the tube radius, while having an eye on the topology. However, The odd-bevel, (which gives you decent topo at the junction,) puts an extra edge at the mirror-seam. So..

- Remove the *Subdivision*, convert to mesh, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>  dissolve the unwanted edge.

Then you can re-assign modifiers: *Solidify*, *Bevel* (by angle, 2 segments, 'Shape' 1) and the *Subdivision*.

[image]